# Custom Iban data annotation clientside validation

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently working on a form and would like to have the IBAN validation responsive @client side. The standard c# .net data annotations are all working but i have a problem with my custom IBAN data annotation.The unobtrusive jquery plugin is what i'm using to get the errormessages to the client but thats not doing the trick for the iban validation. The iban validation attribute does work on submit but i would like to have a direct reponsive.

I have seen some posts where they implement the IClientModelValidator but i dont have a clue how to do this in this situation.

```
 public static class IbanValidator
{
    public static bool Validate(string iban)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(iban))
            return false;

        return ValidateChecksum(iban.ToUpper());
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Validates IBAN checksum
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="iban">IBAN string</param>
    /// <returns>true/false</returns>
    private static bool ValidateChecksum(string iban)
    {
        if (iban.Length < 4 || iban[0] == ' ' || iban[1] == ' ' || iban[2] == ' ' || iban[3] == ' ')
            return false;

        var checksum = 0;
        var ibanLength = iban.Length;

        for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex < ibanLength; charIndex++)
        {
            if (iban[charIndex] == ' ') continue;

            int value;
            var c = iban[(charIndex + 4) % ibanLength];
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            {
                value = c - '0';
            }
            else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            {
                value = c - 'A';
                checksum = (checksum * 10 + value / 10 + 1) % 97;
                value %= 10;
            }
            else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            {
                value = c - 'a';
                checksum = (checksum * 10 + value / 10 + 1) % 97;
                value %= 10;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

            checksum = (checksum * 10 + value) % 97;
        }

        return checksum == 1;
    }
}


public class IbanValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return IbanValidator.Validate(value as string)
            ? ValidationResult.Success
            : new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage(validationContext));
    }

    private string GetErrorMessage(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        LocService errorTranslation = validationContext.GetService(typeof(LocService)) as LocService;
        return errorTranslation.GetLocalizedHtmlString("ErrorMessage_Invalid_Iban");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would still need to create a separate Js file that handles the client side validation.

Example:

```
// Value is the element to be validated, params is the array of name/value 
$.validator.addMethod("iban", function (value, element, params) {
    // Code here
});
```

You'll then need to add it to the unobtrusive adapters:

- jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool - used when your validator does not need any additional data.
- jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal - used when your validator takes in one piece of additional data.
- jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addMinMax - used when your validator deals with minimum and maximum values such as range or string length.

**OR:**

`jquery-validation` offers the Client side validation as plugin:
https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/additional/iban.js